# Error checking simple Calculator

Tags: c++

I'm having a little bit of trouble error checking if the user divides by 0.
if the user requests a division by 0 the result string should indicate that it is illegal to perform a divide by zero. it should look like this:

> Your operation is division: 6/0   Illegal Operation!

However I have no clue how to get it to look like that. so far I can only `std::cout` a "this is illegal" message, but the output ends up looking like this:

> This is illegal!Your operation is : 6 / 0=-858993460

I've also tried to set results to a different string in the else statement. It just ignores it.

how would I end up coding this?

```
void Simplecalc::setOperation(char oper, int op1, int op2)
{
operation = oper;
number1 = op1;
number2 = op2;
    if(operation == '+')
    {
    answer = number1 + number2;
    type ="addition";
    }
    else if(operation =='-')
    {
        answer = number1 - number2;
        type ="subtraction";
    }
    else if(operation =='*')
    {
        answer = number1 * number2;
        type = "multiplication";
    }
    else if(operation =='/')
    {
        if(number2 != 0)
    {
         answer = number1/number2;
         type = "division";
    }
   else
       {
     cout<<"this is illegal!";

        }


    }

    else if(operation =='%')
    {
        answer = number1%number2;
        type ="modulus";
    }


}

string Simplecalc::getResults()
{

stringstream ss;
    ss <<"Your operation is "<<type<<": "<<number1<<" "<<operation<<" "<<number2<<"="    
    <<answer<<"\n";
results =ss.str();


   return results;
}
```

Comment: You must also check the 2nd operand of the % operation.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are calling getResult()  after setOperation () function. This is happening even if the operation is illegal.

Why don't you just use a flag for this. Set a bool flag to false if the operation is illegal. Use that flag to defer the call to getResults() for illegal case.

```
if(flag)
{
    getResults();
}
```

else
    {
       //do nothing
     }

Hope That solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-designing. There's no need to have a concept of "setting an operation". You should just read input, perform validation, and write the output, all in one method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize 'answer' with '0'. You are getting -858993460 (equal to hexadecimal 0xcccccccc) which is the default value of answer variable.